# How to prevent PHP from renaming '&times' to 'x' symbol?

Tags: php

I have with an unwanted replaced, and not able to figure out how to fix it.

When you `echo` the following `string` in PHP

```
echo('?hash=123&rid=111&timestamp=123');
```

The output is:

```
?hash=123&rid=111×tamp=123
```

Note that `&timestamp` has been replaced with `×tamp`

I tried to escape it by using `\&timestamp` but that doens't work.

How can I prevent PHP replacing this?

*You can reproduce this error online using http://phptester.net/*

Comment: `&times;` is the HTML equivalent. Quote the `&` as `&amp;`. Conclusion: You need to [escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities) URLs.

Comment: @Markus Not "quote", but *encode*. And to avoid confusion, the URL needs to be *HTML-encoded*, not URL-encoded.

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like that testing website doesn't escape the _input_, so when it gets run, the input itself shows the times table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape that string, because & is a special symbol in HTML.

```
echo htmlspecialchars('?hash=123&rid=111&timestamp=123');
```

More information on the PHP site: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Ah, thanks. That was the issue, I did not even think about it being a HTML character. Thanks for helping out.